# How to let script only show in homepage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, header

I need to include script code schema only on homepage of my website.

But, I do not know too much about PHP code, I cant filter them based on that so I was wondering is there a way to include script code schema ONLY on homepage URL and not to show it on any other page.

I tried using this :

```
<?php if( is_front_page() ): ?>
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  { 
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": ...
    ...
  }
  </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Try also `is_home()`. And see an example here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239838

Comment: Hey @Slava, I tried but it's not work :(

Comment: What is your home page now? How was it managed?

Comment: What's the url of your homepage? `website.com` or `website.com/stuff`?

Comment: Is this even wordpress or just raw php?

Comment: @Slava I think that my home page is PHP, It's managed by CMS created by hand code.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy My homepage's url is `website.com`

Comment: @blahy It's just php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Dump it on your homepage to figure out what your homepage url is, for example for me the url is: `http://localhost:3000/index.php` so my `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for that page will be `/index.php`. For you depending on the config it can be just `/` or any other value. Note that value and use that in your if check:

```
<?php

var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/index.php') {
  echo 'its homepage';
}
```

Output on index.php:

```
string(10) "/index.php" its homepage
```

Output on other.php:

```
string(10) "/other.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code in your functions.php

```
function add_inline_script() {
?>
<?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ): ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function()
{

});
</script>
<?php endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_inline_script', 0 );
```